# Comparing the sums of categorical and individual data in the same column in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset of almost half a million rows. To summarize, it looks like this

```
ages   totals year sex subcounty county
0-4   500     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
0     100     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
1     150     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
2     50      2015 M   subcounty1 county1
3     100     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
4     100     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
5-9   1000    2015 M   subcounty1 county1
5     300     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
6     200     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
7     200     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
8     200     2015 M   subcounty1 county1
9     50      2015 M   subcounty1 county1
0-4   2000    2017 F   subcounty1 county1
0     700     2017 F   subcounty1 county1
1     250     2017 F   subcounty1 county1
2     300     2017 F   subcounty1 county1
3     250     2017 F   subcounty1 county1
4     500     2017 F   subcounty1 county1
```

the individual ages and age groups repeat so on for year,sex, sub county and county. The source of the dataset is not reliable so I want to confirm that the sums of the totals actually correspond to each other. Basically, I want to take the totals sum of 0,1,2,3,4 and compare it to that corresponding total for 0-4. I want to repeat this for every single age group for each year,sex,subcounty and county (it's a large dataset). I usually use dplyr but not sure if I should use another package for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should filter out any groups with issues. It assumes the first row of each age group has the range in `ages`, and looks for a `"-"` character in `ages` to tell when a new group starts---you may need to adjust that logic if your data doesn't always match that pattern (e.g., if you have an "85+" age group you may need to change the regex pattern to `"[-+]"` and set `fixed = FALSE`).

```
df %>%
  mutate(age_group = ifelse(grepl("-", ages, fixed = TRUE), ages, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(age_group, .direction = "down") %>%
  group_by(age_group, year, sex, subcounty, county) %>%
  mutate(
    check_total = ifelse(grepl("-", ages, fixed = TRUE), sum(totals) - totals, totals)
  ) %>%
  filter(any(check_total != totals))
# # A tibble: 6 × 8
# # Groups:   age_group, year, sex, subcounty, county [1]
#   ages  totals  year sex   subcounty  county  age_group check_total
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>           <int>
# 1 5-9     1000  2015 M     subcounty1 county1 5-9               950
# 2 5        300  2015 M     subcounty1 county1 5-9               300
# 3 6        200  2015 M     subcounty1 county1 5-9               200
# 4 7        200  2015 M     subcounty1 county1 5-9               200
# 5 8        200  2015 M     subcounty1 county1 5-9               200
# 6 9         50  2015 M     subcounty1 county1 5-9                50
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked. The 80+ is actually categorized for all above 80 but with no individual numbers so getting rid of that group gave me zero results (was screwing up 75-79, guessing it was missing it up with 80?) which is awesome! Thank you again!

Comment: Question, if also want to do another check. The ages column also has a "Total" that represents the total per each subcounty by age and year. I wanted to compare that total to the sum of the age groups (0-4,5-9,etc). I was trying to modify the code to do that, I would have to get rid of the grepl function and just input "Total" for the ifelse?

Comment: Yeah, but you'd also need to be careful about what you're checking--if you just `sum(totals)` it would add up the `totals` for each age AND each age group subtotal, double counting everything. You might do better to split your data into pieces, 1 piece with the individual ages, 1 piece with the age ranges, and one piece with the "Total", sum up the `totals` column in each piece (by group), and then join them back together.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! Was thinking of doing a join but wanted to check before! Thank you so much for the help!